# How do I define a custom variable cref name?

Tags: lemma, cref

I am trying to set up names for lemmas via the theorem package such that I can name lemmas.
This is because remembering what lemma 15 does vs lemma 4 is difficult. Therefore I would like to name each lemma and have a separate counter for each category/name of lemmas, for example math and logic.
There are two problems with this approach.

- I can not add text between the "Lemma" and the counter (I want Lemma Logic 1)
- I can not get cleverref (`\cref`) to use that name so that it `\cref{lmm:test1}` results in "lemma Logic 1".

```
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}{Logic}
    If $P$ then $Q$.
    \label{lmm:test1}
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}{Logic}
    If $Q$ then $R$.
    \label{lmm:test2}
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}{Math}
    $2+2=4$
    \label{lmm:test3}
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}{Logic}
    If $R$ then $S$
    \label{lmm:test4}
\end{lemma}


Text \cref{lmm:test1} goes \cref{lmm:test2} in \cref{lmm:test3} here \cref{lmm:test4}. 


\end{document}
```

[image: The image using the vanilla mtheorem package with a \newtheorem{lemma}]

I tried instead not using the mtheorem package where I defined my own lemma command as such:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ifcounter[1]{%
  \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\lemma}[1]{
    \ifcounter{#1}{
        \stepcounter{#1}
    }{
        \newcounter{#1}
        \setcounter{#1}{0}
        \refstepcounter{#1}
        \crefname{#1}{lemma #1}{lemmas #1}
        \Crefname{#1}{Lemma #1}{Lemmas #1} 
    }

    \paragraph{Lemma #1 \arabic{#1}}
}
```

This results in the correct format of the lemmas itself but breaks the crefs.

[image]

Is there a (cleaner) way or maybe even better format that is supported to implement this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Wouldn't it be easier to just define a `\newtheorem{lemmal}{Lemma Logic}` and a `\newtheorem{lemmam}{Lemma Math}`? This way, they each have their counter, they each can be referred to with `\cref{}`, etc. Or maybe I misunderstood the question

Comment: @KersoulMan
Thank you for welcoming me.
Creating new theorem environments using ```\newtheorem{lemmal}{Lemma Logic}``` and ```\newtheorem{lemmam}{Lemma Math}``` for each category is indeed much better. Thank you.

(I don't know how to mark your answer as the correct one)